# autenticação facebook mongodb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, mongodb

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de autenticação com facebook, uso ruby on rails e mongodb.
Preciso fazer a integração do device com a api do facebook(entenda como qualquer outra rede social, também), para o sistema.

Não encontro material consistente para realizar esta tarefa, preciso de ajuda de vocês.
Mesmo com as correções e com as ajudas de como postar estou grato pela atenção e a possível ajuda pertinente!

Answer (score 0):

O One Bit Code é um blog que sempre oferece material de qualidade. Para o seu problema é só acessar este tutorial [Criando autenticação com o Facebook em 10 minutos! (Devise + Omniauth)](http://onebitcode.com/criando-autenticacao-com-o-facebook-em-10-minutos-devise-omniauth/)

E tem també a documentação oficial do [Omniauth](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)

Comment: É, muito boa essa fonte, a questão é que estou usando mongodb e gostaria de um material que trate dessa questão!